# How to transform my python project to an executable application that works on any computer not juste mine

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I use the cx_Freeze method to transform my python code to .exe file and it works fine on my pc but when I try it on another pc it shows an error that he didn't find the path C:\Users\Akram..
here's my setup.py file

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"
executables = [Executable("general.py", base=base, icon='accept.ico')]
#Renseignez ici la liste complète des packages utilisés par votre application
packages = ["idna", "__future__", "PyQt5","sys", "numpy", "cv2", "pyzbar", "validate_email", "urllib.request", "mysql.connector", "datetime", "face_recognition"]
options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'packages':packages,
        'include_files':['icones','TEACH_images']


    },
}
setup(
    name = "bis",
    options = options,
    version = "1.0",
    description = 'Voici mon programme',
    executables = executables
)
```

python setup.py build:    this is the cmd command

Here's the error when my friend open the application on his PC:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCBRv.png)

Comment: Where are you using this ```C:\Users\Akram``` in your code ? And why does that path exists in others PC ?

Comment: I didn't use the C:\Users\Akram in my code but it is the project path. The problem is that .exe file didn't work in other PC

Answer (score 0):

use pyinstaller instead, because it creates an .exe that can be used on any computer.

you can use the command in command prompt `pyinstaller setup.py --onefile` then hit enter

Comment: I use pyinstaller setup.py --onefile  I didn't get the .exe file. Please can you explain me all the steps to do it

Comment: There are a bunch of good videos explaining this, take a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZX5kH72Yx4&ab_channel=TechWithTim) one

Comment: or this one [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-python-script-to-exe-file/)

Comment: I watch the videos and the link ad I try to search and search for how to use pyinstaller but still dosen't work, I didn't get the .exe file so please can you show me how to use it

Comment: Find the directory the .py file is in and open cmd from there. Next type in the command from above and then look in the folder /dist. The .exe should be there